# Trying to update Google Groups with PATCH via Javascript

Tags: google-groups-api

I am trying to update a Google Group using PATCH and cannot get it to work. I am not sure if it is a syntax issue or it cannot be done via Javascript. I can successfully perform a "get" operation using OAUTH, but not the PATCH.

1. Should I be using OAuth or Bearer in setRequestHeader "Authorization" (both seem to work fine for the GET and fail in the same manner during "PATCH".
2. The get works fine. The error on PATCH is { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid", "message": "Permission denied: Cannot hide from Groups directory." } ], "code": 400, "message": "Permission denied: Cannot hide from Groups directory." } }

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Untitled Document</title>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function loadXMLDoc() {
   var xmlhttppatcher;
   var xmlhttp;
   var data;   
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xmlhttppatcher = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlhttppatcher.open("PATCH","https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/nogads2%40mydomain.org", false);
   xmlhttppatcher.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   xmlhttppatcher.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + "ya29.AHES6ZR_yljyMvWCv0gWbwIASYYp29S8rFUA-dd-YkyyjTHz");
   //xmlhttppatcher.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "ya29.AHES6ZR_yljyMvWCv0gWbwIASYYp29S8rFUA-dd-YkyyjTHz");
   data = '{"replyTo": "REPLY_TO_MANAGERS"}';
   alert(data);
   xmlhttppatcher.send(data);
   alert('Your data was sent');
   document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerHTML = xmlhttppatcher.responseText;
   alert('readystate: ' + xmlhttppatcher.readyState + ' status: ' + xmlhttppatcher.status); //this should return 4 & 200
   if (xmlhttppatcher.status == 200)
   alert("The request succeeded!\n\nThe response representation was:\n\n" + xmlhttppatcher.responseText);
   else
   alert("The request did not succeed!\n\nThe response status was: " + xmlhttppatcher.status + " " + xmlhttppatcher.statusText + ".");
   }
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/nogads2%40mydomain.org?alt=json", false);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + "ya29.AHES6ZR_yljyMvWCv0gWbwIASYYp29S8rFUA-dd-YkyyjTHz");
   xmlhttp.send();
   alert('readystate: ' + xmlhttp.readyState + ' status: ' + xmlhttp.status); //this should return 4 & 200
   document.getElementById("myDiv2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
   alert("The request succeeded!\n\nThe response representation was:\n\n" + xmlhttp.responseText);
   else
   alert("The request did not succeed!\n\nThe response status was: " + xmlhttp.status + " " + xmlhttp.statusText + ".");
   }
   }
   </script>
   </head>

   <body>
   <div id="myDiv1"><h2>Let AJAX change this text (DIV1)</h2></div><br />
   <div id="myDiv2"><h2>Let AJAX change this text (DIV2)</h2></div>
   <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
   </body>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got the same problem, and I fixed it by creating a new Groups object[Java] and just setting the specific attribute that I wanted to update